# Compare 2 files based on the first column and print the not matched

Tags: awk, sed, grep, diff, file-comparison

**File# 1:**

```
test1,1
test2,2
test3
```

**File# 2:**

```
test2
test1
test4
```

**Desired Output:**

```
test4
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for a bit more? The first column doesn't match on any line.

Comment: @user1794469 i would like to `print` what in `file2` which is not in `file1` based on `1st` column. which is `test4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
$ grep -vwf <(cut -d, -f1 file1) file2
test4
```

#### Explanation

- `grep` options:

  ```
  -v, --invert-match
        Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
  -w, --word-regexp
        Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form 
        whole words.  
  -f FILE, --file=FILE
        Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.
  ```

  So, combined, `grep -vwf patternFile inputFile` means "find those lines from patternFile which are never present as whole words in inputFile".
- `<(command)`: this is called process substitution and, in the shells that support it (e.g. bash) it will essentially act like a file. This enables us to use the output of the `cut` command as a "file" for grep's `-f` option.
- `cut -d, -f1 file1`: print only the 1st, comma-separated field of file1.

Note that you might want to use `-x` (match entire line) instead of just `-w` if your data are really as you show:

```
  -x, --line-regexp
          Select  only  those  matches  that exactly match the whole line.
```

So:

```
$ grep -vxf <(cut -d, -f1 file1) file2
test4
```

Also, if your `file1` can contain any regular expression characters (`.`, `*`, `?` etc.) you might want to use `-F` as well:

```
  -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions.
```

So:

```
$ grep -Fvxf <(cut -d, -f1 file1) file2
test4
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `cut` and `grep`:

```
grep -F -x -v -f <(cut -d',' -f1 file1) file2
```

`cut -d',' -f1 file1` prints the first field of `file1` and `grep` is using the output as pattern input file (option `-f`).
Options `-F` and `-x` are used to match fixed-strings and whole lines and `-v` inverses the matches.

Comment: Heh, [great minds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567441/22222) :)

Comment: Looking at your description I'm just the lazy mind :)

Answer (score 1):

```
:~$ cat > toto
a b
c d
e f
:~$ cat > titi
a b
d e
f g
:~$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] == 0' toto titi
d e
f g
```

This is only an example I get from my examples list, you might use it to workaround for your own needs.

Comment: Close but see [my comment to bushman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567426/compare-2-files-based-on-the-first-column-and-print-the-not-matched/567699#comment1055605_567439)

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` possibilty assuming first field in `file1` contains the file name and the field separator is always a `,`

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{test[$1]=1}NR!=FNR{if (!test[$1]) print $1}' file1 file2
```

(See @Terdon streamlined version in the comments, and then combining with mine

```
awk -F"," 'NR==FNR{test[$1]++}!test[$1]{print $1}' file1 file2
```

)

Alternative using `join`

```
join -t, -v2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: `!test[$1]` will fill `test[]` with all the `$1`s from file2. `!($1 in test)` will be much less of a memory hog ad when you do that you don't need to store any values in `test[]`, e.g. by incrementing it. The idiomatic answer is `awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} !($1 in a)' file1 file2`. The reason memory usage is an issue is that people often use this approach to select a few lines from a massive file.

Answer (score 0):

For exactly that setup,

```
grep -ffile2 -v file1
test3
```

will do. But - be aware of e.g. false positives which would need additional measures to be taken.

Comment: could you please check my edit. because i tested with the same command but it's not giving the actual output.